# Check via apex if current ORG is on deployment

Tags: apex, deployment, user

I have a class that update users on success but whenever our release team is doing a deployment on the org this action still retrieves success but doesn't make the update.

Is there a way I can check via apex code if org is on deployment so I can display an error message for users?

Comment: try to use Metadata API and its checkStatus() method https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_checkdeploystatus.htm

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi can you attach an example? Cause I've never try this and I'm a little bit lost. Thanks in advance!